# Python Multistage Docker build with setup.py

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to rewrite my Python Docker build to a multistage build. I have been mimicking [this guide](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/) in order to do so.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim AS compile

RUN apt-get upgrade && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH='/opt/venv/bin:$PATH'

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install gunicorn

ADD src/ .
ADD setup.py .
RUN pip install .

FROM python:3.8-slim AS build

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

COPY --from=compile /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH ='opt/venv/bin:$PATH'

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID WWW
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G WWW WWW -s /bin/sh && chown WWW:WWW -R /var/www

USER WWW

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn"]
CMD ["-w", "4", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "src:wsgi"]
```

Here is the `setup.py`. It currently holds just random data from [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), and looks like this. I suspect the error is at `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`, though I cannot find out how to fix it.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE", # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description="long_description",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

On Step 11/24, when runnint `pip install .` the compilation halts with only `Processing /` as information. This is probably due to my setup script, however I have not found a way to fix it.

```
Step 9/24 : ADD src/ .
 ---> d51425cd9672
Step 10/24 : ADD setup.py .
 ---> 2d0378201b2a
Step 11/24 : RUN pip install .
 ---> Running in a747453f98a5
Processing /
```

Here is the file structure of my project

```
❯ tree
.
|-- Dockerfile
|-- bin
|   |-- activate
|   |-- activate.csh
|   |-- activate.fish
|   |-- easy_install
|   |-- easy_install-3.7
|   |-- pip
|   |-- pip3
|   |-- pip3.7
|   |-- python -> python3
|   `-- python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
|-- foo.log
|-- include
|-- lib
|   `-- python3.7
|       `-- site-packages
            ...
            lots of files...
            ...

|-- pyvenv.cfg
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.py
`-- src
    |-- app.py
    `-- wsgi.py
```

I have had the build working as a singe stage build, bu then without the src folder, and app.py and wsgi.py directly inside project folder.

Any help is appreciated!

----------UPDATE---------

I have tried running the `pip install .` locally in another location with only src/ folder and setup.py with the following result:

Here is the output:

```
Processing /Users/xxx/xxx/test
Building wheels for collected packages: example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE
  Building wheel for example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE: filename=example_pkg_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE-0.0.1-cp37-none-any.whl size=1391 sha256=0d2d6eca20042c47f1cbe6a022949e2770f167ae6324a8c2f8ff473baaac7fa7
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/7v/5w20zhw90g31z2cl95qngb_80000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-e_jn3t7n/wheels/50/63/3f/b109a0dbe8dbf853eb63d219a39f3e501c43d52305bc1c5b38
Successfully built example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE
Installing collected packages: example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE
Successfully installed example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE-0.0.1
```

Comment: So installation just halts without any additional logs?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It is still running but provides no output or anything. Probably for 20 min or so now.

Comment: Did you try to do it locally? I mean copy `src` and `setup.py` to some destination and run command `pip install .` in that destination?

Comment: Good idea! I´ve just tried it and it installed successfully. I´ve updated the post with the results

Comment: How about you `ls` in both your test dir and docker? I mean add for now `RUN ls` just before `RUN pip listall .`. And compare the contents. Maybe you added whole `src` folder to your test destination locally but added only contents of this folder during docker build process. Is so then `ADD src/ ./src` should solve the problem.

Comment: When I ```ls```into my test dir, only src folder and setup.py are present. When I try to ls or mkdir in the dockercontainer I get the following error ```/bin/sh: 1: ls: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ls' returned a non-zero code: 127```. The error message and error code are the same for both commands. I have tried adding ```ls```to ``apt-get install ... `` line I get the error: ``E: Unable to locate package ls
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc ls' returned a non-zero code: 100``, which I find quite strange.

Comment: Anyway I suggest you try `ADD src/ ./src`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that. I did add that line, and landed on the original error of ``Processing /``

Comment: Is this a mistake or does your dockerfile have duplicated `FROM python:3.8-slim AS build` declaration just after `pip install` ?

Comment: use `WORKDIR` before you start copying stuff into image, e.g. `RUN mkdir /io`, then `WORKDIR /io`, then `COPY requirements.txt .`, `RUN pip install .` and stuff. I'd also say that right now, `find_packages()` collects packages from the root dir, scanning the whole chroot, so your suspicion seems to be correct.

Comment: Another option is to restrict `find_packages` lookup by providing the `where` argument, e.g. `packages = find_packages(where="src")`, but only if you are using the `src` layout (`src` dir is not a package itself).

Comment: This confuses me a bit: `RUN apt-get upgrade && apt-get update`. Shouldn't it be `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the working directory, as you are copying all your code to the root dir. When you then run `pip install .` from `/`, [pip copies the entire filesystem](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#id44) to a temporary directory in order to install from there. I wonder what happens if you wait for it to finish?

Also, I think that one of the earlier lines might be wrong. I usually do `apt update && apt -y upgrade` and not the other way around.

Try this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim AS compile

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH='/opt/venv/bin:$PATH'

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install gunicorn

# To match the directory structure at host:
ADD src/ ./src
ADD setup.py .
RUN pip install .
```

For more information on how to write dockerfiles for the Python images, see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).